# How to fix Genexus 16 U 4 cannot find symbol createMasterPage?

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to update my Genexus 16 U3 Kb to U4 and I'm having issues with all objects on compiling, throwing cannot file symbol for method createMasterPage, a method I think should be defined on gxclassR.jar

I have already tried rebuild all a couple times and making a new environment with new settings with no success.

RwdMasterPage by itself compiles with no errors.

This is an example of the error:

```
com\parametros\parmmodelo\comportamiento\actualizacionparametro_impl.java:185: error: cannot find symbol
         MasterPageObj= createMasterPage(remoteHandle, "com.parametros.rwdmasterpage");
                        ^
  symbol:   method createMasterPage(int,String)
  location: class actualizacionparametro_impl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That createMasterPage function is defined in the gxclassr.jar (source is https://github.com/genexuslabs/JavaClasses/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/genexus/webpanels/GXWebPanel.java), so for some reason, your compiler is not finding the right gxclassr.jar in the classpath.

Comment: That was the answer, The Genexus u4 installer didn't updated the correct resources to the install path. 

In order to fix it I had to uninstall and then delete all the resources on the genexus 16 install folder.